# totally confused about login: is it for stackexchnage or just individual site, e.g., mathematica.stackexchange

Tags: support, user-accounts, login

I had or have at least two accounts, one originally with mathematica.stackexchange.com for which my login was via Facebook (or possibly Google), which in turn used, let's call it, email-address-1. Subsequently I went also to tex.stackexchnage.com, got a "Join this community" link when I tried to post, and so created a login using, let's call it, email-address-2.

I just allegedly merged the two accounts. Nonetheless, my profile info still shows two different accounts, one for each of the two email-address -- actually, it shows THREE possible logins now, one via Facebook using email-address-1, another via Google using email-address-1, and the third direct, using email-address-2.

How do I straighten this all out?

As indicated, I already had completed the "merge two accounts" process. supposedly.

And I'm still confused: is a login for stackexchnage as a whole, or just for an individual stack exchange community.

Comment: When you merge accounts you also merge login methods, you can see all of your login methods under Settings -> My logins (on your profile page). I have three login methods. I don't quite understand what you mean when you say that it shows two different accounts, but the way it usually works is that we all have one account for each site, and then we have a main account that is used for chat. Wherever you login and whichever login method you use of the ones you have configured you will have access to all of your StackExchange accounts after that.

Comment: i.e. "merging accounts" doesn't mean you get to combine your reputation so that the reputation you have here can also be used on tex.SE, that aspect is kept separate. Merging accounts means merging two different sets of site accounts, if you were to have say three accounts on Mathematica.SE and two on Tex.SE, then after a merger you would have one Mathematica.SE account and one Tex.SE account.